# Should I reheat my eggs before using in recipe?

Tags: eggs, cooking-time, reheating

I premade scrambled eggs tonight for this recipe (very early tailgate party tomorrow, don’t judge): https://www.hgtv.com/design/make-and-celebrate/entertaining/ham-egg-and-cheese-croissant-wrap

My question is should I reheat the eggs first in the oven before adding them to the crescent rolls and baking them? Or will the 15-18 minutes the recipe calls for be enough to warm the eggs through?

Answer (score 2):

The time in the oven should be plenty for heating the eggs.